# Invalid Redirect_uri For instagram login using react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-instagram-login

I am using [`react-native-instagram-login`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-instagram-login) for React Native.

Here is my code

```jsx
<InstagramLogin
  ref={instagramLoginRef}
  appId='***********'
  appSecret='*******************'
  scopes={['user_profile', 'user_media']}
  onLoginSuccess={(data) => console.log("Success")}
  onLoginFailure={(data) => console.log("Fail " +  JSON.stringify(data))}
/>
```

I am getting following error

> ```
> {"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Invalid redirect_uri"}
> ```

In Instagram Developer Console what should I add as redirect Uri as this is not a website but an react native app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started):

> **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs**
>
> Enter your website’s URL. Normally this
>   would be a dedicated URI that can capture redirect query string
>   parameters, but for this tutorial your website’s URL will be fine.
>
> For example: `https://socialsizzle.heroku.com/auth/`
>
> After you enter a URL, save your changes and check the URL again; we
>   may have appended a trailing forward slash depending your URL
>   structure. Copy the complete URL somewhere since you will need it in
>   later steps to get authorization codes and access tokens.

At this [example code](https://github.com/hungdev/react-native-instagram-login/blob/master/Example/App.js#L51-L58), we see the `redirectUrl='https://www.google.com'`, which means that you can set whatever you want. It is useful for collecting login data statistics and to have a backend endpoint for logging.

```jsx
<InstagramLogin
  ref={instagramLoginRef}
  clientId="931cca1d0c154de3aafd83300ff8b288"
  redirectUrl="https://google.com"
  scopes={['basic']}
  onLoginSuccess={token => this.setState({ token })}
  onLoginFailure={data => this.setState({ failure: data })}
/>
```

Also have a look at this issue ["no response when completed"](https://github.com/hungdev/react-native-instagram-login/issues/27) which it says that `redirectUrl` has to start with a `www` because of a bug in `react-native-webview`. Also at this issue, you'll see that the user example code has a Firebase function endpoint URL `redirectUrl="https://us-central1-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/url_get&response_type=token"` so it uses Firebase to log/feedback login requests.

Finally, in *Facebook Developer Console*, you just enter the *Valid OAuth Redirect URIs*:

[image: Facebook Developer Console]

which means that you enter which URLs you accept for the API to redirect; it's more like a security mechanism but you have to enter your redirect URL there, or else the API won't work.

Comment: I am using this sdk  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-instagram-login . Here i have appId &  appSecret. And the link which u sent is also pointing to same yarn add react-native-instagram-login and that link says  clientId & requestUrl.

Comment: @VjLxmi I'm writing about the same module as you can see from the [issue link](https://github.com/hungdev/react-native-instagram-login/issues/27) and the source code of `<InstagramLogin/>` component. I've attached this issue so for you to see that the problem that person describes uses `redirectUrl` with a Firebase Functions endpoint. Also this [example code](https://github.com/hungdev/react-native-instagram-login/blob/master/Example/App.js#L51-L58) code I've linked shows the `redirectUrl` is pointed out to `https://www.google.com`. Every link I've posted refers `redirectUrl`.

Comment: Thanks now it works. I had added `https://www.google.com` previously in my code and hence it was not working. later i came to know that facebook dev console on saving redirect url appends `"/"` at the end. So now in redirectUrl i am passing `https://www.google.com/`  with a slash and now it works. Thanks