# Code for Facebook and Google Login not working on live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-7

Laravel version : 7.9.2
PHP version: 7.4

I have code for login with Facebook and Google. It's working absolutely fine on localhost but on live server it doesn't work. Surprising thing is It neither returns any error nor throw any exception. 
It simply redirect user back to login page and my URL shows the string **#*=***. 
This is live link

```
https://beta.car-chain.net/login
```

I need suggestion.

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use App\User;
use Exception;


    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        use AuthenticatesUsers;

        protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }

        protected $providers = [
            'github','facebook','google','twitter'
        ];

        public function show()
        {
            return view('auth.login');
        }

        public function redirectToProvider($driver)
        {
            if( ! $this->isProviderAllowed($driver) ) {
                return $this->sendFailedResponse("{$driver} is not currently supported");
            }

            try {
                return Socialite::driver($driver)->redirect();
            } catch (Exception $e) {


                // You should show something simple fail message
                return $this->sendFailedResponse($e->getMessage());
            }
        }


        public function handleProviderCallback( $driver )
        {
            try {
                $user = Socialite::driver($driver)->user();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return $this->sendFailedResponse($e->getMessage());
            }

            // check for email in returned user
            return empty( $user->email )
                ? $this->sendFailedResponse("No email id returned from {$driver} provider.")
                : $this->loginOrCreateAccount($user, $driver);
        }

        protected function sendSuccessResponse()
        {
            return redirect()->intended('home');
        }

        protected function sendFailedResponse($msg = null)
        {
            return redirect()->route('social.login')
                ->withErrors(['msg' => $msg ?: 'Unable to login, try with another provider to login.']);
        }

        protected function loginOrCreateAccount($providerUser, $driver)
        {

         // check for already has account
         $user = User::where('email', $providerUser->getEmail())->first();

     // if user already found
             if( $user ) {
                 // update the avatar and provider that might have changed
                 $user->update([
                     'provider' => $driver,
                     'provider_id' => $providerUser->id,
                     'access_token' => $providerUser->token
                 ]);
             } else {
                   if($providerUser->getEmail()){ //Check email exists or not. If exists create a new user
                    $user = User::create([
                       'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                       'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                       'provider' => $driver,
                       'provider_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                       'access_token' => $providerUser->token,
                       'password' => '' // user can use reset password to create a password
                 ]);

                  }else{

                 //Show message here what you want to show

                }
           }

           // login the user
             Auth::login($user, true);
             return $this->sendSuccessResponse();
       }

        private function isProviderAllowed($driver)
        {
            return in_array($driver, $this->providers) && config()->has("services.{$driver}");
        }

    }
```

Route.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('auth/social', 'Auth\LoginController@show')->name('social.login');
Route::get('oauth/{driver}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')->name('social.oauth');
Route::get('oauth/{driver}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback')->name('social.callback');
```

Comment: I think you have to go and add you domain URL and redirect URL to the Facebook/Google developer panels for the corresponding apps. See one related questions of mine regarding instagram [Invalid Redirect_uri For instagram login using react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374528/invalid-redirect-uri-for-instagram-login-using-react-native/60437199#60437199).

Comment: @ChristosLytras
Could you please point out where I already have added my url into "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" for facebook. Still it's not working